limitar el uso de ram de una aplicacion como spotify en debian 12 linux
estoy intentando limitar la RAM para spotify pero no consigo activarlo, estoy intentando crear un servicio para limitar la app
detalles de systemctl:
\
`root@debian12-jos:/home/josdev# sudo systemctl start spotify.service
Job for spotify.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
See "systemctl status spotify.service" and "journalctl -xeu spotify.service" for details.
root@debian12-jos:/home/josdev# sudo systemctl status spotify.service
× spotify.service - Spotify Music Player
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/spotify.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: signal) since Sun 2024-06-23 11:57:32 -05; 18s ago
Duration: 71ms
Process: 10169 ExecStart=/usr/bin/spotify (code=killed, signal=SEGV)
Main PID: 10169 (code=killed, signal=SEGV)
CPU: 67ms
jun 23 11:57:32 debian12-jos systemd\[1\]: spotify.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
jun 23 11:57:32 debian12-jos systemd\[1\]: Stopped spotify.service - Spotify Music Player.
jun 23 11:57:32 debian12-jos systemd\[1\]: spotify.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
jun 23 11:57:32 debian12-jos systemd\[1\]: spotify.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
jun 23 11:57:32 debian12-jos systemd\[1\]: Failed to start spotify.service - Spotify Music Player.
jun 23 11:57:39 debian12-jos systemd\[1\]: spotify.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
jun 23 11:57:39 debian12-jos systemd\[1\]: spotify.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
jun 23 11:57:39 debian12-jos systemd\[1\]: Failed to start spotify.service - Spotify Music Player.\`

aqui el sporify service
GNU nano 7.2                             /etc/systemd/system/spotify.service  
\[Unit\]
Description=Spotify Music Player
After=network.target

\[Service\]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/spotify
MemoryHigh=512M  # Limita a 512 MB de RAM
Restart=always

\[Install\]
WantedBy=default.target

el hardware de la pc es la siguiente:
root@debian12-jos:/home/josdev# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        3973636 kB
MemFree:          720044 kB
MemAvailable:    1668804 kB
Buffers:           62600 kB
Cached:          1209980 kB
SwapCached:         5340 kB
root@debian12-jos:/home/josdev# cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7400  @ 2.80GHz
stepping    : 10
microcode   : 0xa0b
cpu MHz     : 1596.120
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0


Te doy la bienvenida. Probablemente la pregunta acabará cerrada porque no está directamente relacionada con la programación por lo que creo que podrías tener mejor resultado si la formulases en la comunidad SuperUser https://superuser.com/ (parte de stackexchange), eso sí, tendrás que traducir la pregunta al inglés y las respuestas seguramente las recibirás también en inglés.

Hola Joze, te sugiero que formules tu pregunta, en el foro de Debian, como te dijo ordago, aqui, probablemente, terminará cerrada.

La RAM es como el aire, si limitas su uso Spotify se asfixia y deja de funcionar.
